# Concatenate multiple files' data into one file and also rename the file?

Tags: python

Using python how can I combine all the text file in the specified directory into one text file and rename the output text file with the same filename.

For example: Filea.txt and Fileb_2.txt is in root directory, and it output generated file is Filea_Fileb_2.txt

Filea.txt

```
123123
21321
```

Fileb_2.txt

```
2344
23432
```

Filea_Fileb_2.txt

```
123123
21321
2344
23432
```

my script:

```
PWD1 = /home/jenkins/workspace
files = glob.glob(PWD1 + '/' + '*.txt')
with open(f, 'r') as file:
    for line in (file):
         outputfile = open('outputfile.txt', 'a')
         outputfile.write(line)
         outputfile.close()
```

Comment: grooveplex, I have updated my question with my script..

Comment: What is `PWD1 = Test`?

Comment: The indentation of the code in "my script" doesn't look correct.

Comment: just a folder location. /home/jenkins/workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working solution which stores both file names and file contents in a list, then joins the list filenames and creates a "combined" filename and then adds the contents of all the files to it, because lists append in order that the data is read this is sufficient (my example filenames are filea.txt and fileb.txt but it will work for the filenames you've used):

```
import os
import sys

path = sys.argv[1]
files = []
contents = []
for f in os.listdir(path):
    if f.endswith('.txt'): # in case there are other file types in there
        files.append(str(f.replace('.txt', ''))) #chops off txt so we can join later
        with open(f) as cat:
            for line in cat:
                contents.append(line) # put file contents in list

outfile_name = '_'.join(x for x in files)+'.txt' #create your output filename
outfile = open(outfile_name, 'w')
for line in contents:
    outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()
```

to run this on a specific directory just pass it on the commandline:

```
$python3.6 catter.py /path/to/my_text_files/
```

output filename:

```
filea_fileb.txt
```

contents:

```
123123
21321
2344
23432
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to combine text files.

```
#! python3
from pathlib import Path
import glob


folder_File1 = r"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\CombineFIles"
txt_only = r"\*.txt"

files_File1 = glob.glob(f'{folder_File1}{txt_only}')
new_txt = f'{folder_File1}\\newtxt.txt'

newFile = []
for indx, file in enumerate(files_File1):
    if file == new_txt:
        pass
    else:
        contents = Path(file).read_text()
        newFile.append(contents)

file = open(new_txt, 'w')
file.write("\n".join(newFile))
file.close()
```